# How to find Caloculate in miliseconds in java

Tags: java, swing, datetime, milliseconds

In my stock management project i want to save the time Product is saved. I want to save it in this format. 
date + time(in miliseconds)

So I used this code, which is completely failed I think.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
*
* @author Dilini
*/
public class test {

public void Timemill(final JLabel jl) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                DateFormat smFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                Date date = new Date();
                String smday = smFormat.format(date);
                int itime = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                jl.setText(smday + String.valueOf(itime));
            }
        }
    }).start();

 }
}
```

But result brings something like this.

20140530542

I know 2014=year 05=month 30=day. I can understand 542 is may be seconds. But seconds usually with 0-60. And 542 over that range.. I want to clarify what that is. Also I want to output time with more formatted way.. Thank you.

Comment: 542 is the millisecond part of the current time....

Comment: You should really read the docs for SimpleDateFormat, it even has examples! (And what is that doing in an infinite tight loop?)

Comment: better to save it without formatting, maybe just its long value

Comment: Thanks for your instructions guys..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this and you will see how you can get all parts of a `Date`.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Then use it as appropriate for your particular case.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know what 542 is please help me.

It's the value of `iTime`. You're appending it...

```
jl.setText(smday+String.valueOf(itime));
// ...here -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That value, in turn, comes from:

```
int itime = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

It's the milliseconds portion of the current date/time.

Comment: I knoe it is my dear T.J. Usually when we run date it brings this format 15:04:03 but this was just 3 numbers. That's why I asked. To be honest I copy pasted this "Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) method. I don't have good clear idea. That's why I asked why 542 brings.

Answer (score -1):

Use this format `yyyyMMddHHmmssS` For more information see the Documentation in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

H is the hour
m stand for minute
s for second
S for miliseconds.

542  are miliseconds. You get it here from the `Calendar`

```
int itime = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Change.

```
         DateFormat smFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            Date date = new Date();
            String smday = smFormat.format(date);
            int itime = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
            jl.setText(smday + String.valueOf(itime));
```

TO

```
            DateFormat smFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
            Date date = new Date();
            String smday = smFormat.format(date);
            jl.setText(smday);
```

to format your date in a proper way.

Comment: Thanks whether it is not much complex it brings me the answer.

Comment: @paddy I have added the explanation. Hope now it is ok for you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @pawan the essential parts are copied see the explanation for the placeholder.

Comment: @DavidPostill Have changed my answer.